# responsive cart js doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
    document.querySelector('#menu-btn').onclick = () =>{
    navbar.classList.toggle('active')
    }
let cartitems = document.querySelector('.cart-items-container');
    document.querySelector('#cart-btn').onclick = () =>{
    cartitems .classList.toggle('active')
    }
```

```css
.cart-items-container.active{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
   <div class="fas fa-search" id="search-btn"></div>
   <div class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart-btn">cart btn</div>
   <div class="fas fa-bars" id="menu-btn"></div>
 </div>

     <!--barra di ricerca-->
     <div class="search-from">
        <input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="search here...">
        <label for="search-box" class="fas fa-search"></label>

    </div>  

    <!--0-->
    <div class="cart-items-container">
        <div class="cart-item">

            <span class="fas fa-times"> </span>

                <img src="images/cart-item-1.png" alt="">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>cart item 01</h3>
                    <div class="price">$270/-</div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

i'm doing a responsive menu whit the cart checkout using css and js. The problem is that when i click on the cart, the cart stay hidden and the script dosen't works.

Html

```
 <div class="icons">
   <div class="fas fa-search" id="search-btn"></div>
   <div class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart-btn"></div>
   <div class="fas fa-bars" id="menu-btn"></div>
 </div>

     <!--barra di ricerca-->
     <div class="search-from">
        <input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="search here...">
        <label for="search-box" class="fas fa-search"></label>

    </div>  

    <!--0-->
    <div class="cart-items-container">
        <div class="cart-item">

            <span class="fas fa-times"> </span>

                <img src="images/cart-item-1.png" alt="">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>cart item 01</h3>
                    <div class="price">$270/-</div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Js

```
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
    document.querySelector('#menu-btn').onclick = () =>{
    navbar.classList.toggle('active')
    }
let cartitems = document.querySelector('.cart-items-container');
    document.querySelector('#cart-btn').onclick = () =>{
    cartitems .classList.toggle('active')
    }
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#menu-btn').onclick = () =>` this is working ?

Comment: yep, is working

Comment: working fine your code